# VPN-сервер на Debian

Tags: vpn, debian

Знаю, что сейчас VPN сервер почти никто не использует, но все же помогите, если сможете...

Не хочет подключаться по VPN, даже DNS не пингуется с виндовской машины. Настройка VPN-сервера на Debian

```
apt-get install pptpdnano /etc/ppp/chap-secretslogin * pass 192.168.10.1nano /etc/ppp/pptpd-optionsauthlockdebugnodefaultrouterefuse-paprefuse-chaprefuse-mschaprequire-mschap-v2ms-dns 192.168.1.1logfile /var/log/pptpd.logecho 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward - Форвардинг потом в скрипт добавилiptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.10.0/24 -o eth0 -j SNAT --to ***.***.*.**/etc/init.d/pptpd restart
```

Укажите кто-нибудь на мою ошибку.

Answer (score 2):

Этих настроек недостаточно. Еще должны быть настройки pptpd.conf.

Запущен ли демон?

```
netstat -anp | grep pptpd
```

Правильно ли установлены настройки в `/etc/pptpd.conf`?

```
#должно быть закомментировано, чтобы клиенту передавался его ip-адрес#noipparam#возможно должно быть раскомментировано, для перенаправления пакетовbcrelay eth0#должно указывать IP-адрес сервера в VPN-сетиlocalip#должно указывать диапазон адресов для выдачи VPN-клиентамremoteip
```

Разрешены ли входящие по tcp 1173 (демон слушает по умолчанию)?

```
$IPTABLES -A INPUT -p tcp -s 0/0 --dport 1723 -j ACCEPT
```

pptpd кидает сообщения в лог `/var/log/messages`. Можно там посмотреть, может есть ошибки.

PS. Это то, что приходит в голову на вскидку. Я бы рекомендовал найти в сети полную последовательность шагов по настройке (по словам VPN-сервер PPTPD) и придерживаться ее.